# How to stop or cancel a pending OracleCachedRowSet execution?

Tags: java, database, oracle11g, ojdbc, cachedrowset

Assume the following scenario:
Create an `OracleCachedRowSet` instance using *oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver* then call execute() using a background worker.
Assume that the SQL command is time consuming.
Now, while this instance is still executing, how could I cancel or stop execution and release the active connection?